# Bulk insert for multiple database providers

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, postgresql, bulkinsert

I'm completly new in donet and I'm trying to find a way to write database from c# into a db provider. The data stems from json files, which hold all necessary information for the insertion process (tablesnames, columnnames, types (as strings) and data). Since the amount of data can get quite big I'd like to circumvent creating a new insert statement for every row. Is there an approach that works with all db providers?

From the deserialized json File I'm first creating a DbType array, which holds the datatypes for each column.

With this I tried to get a satisfactory insert approach by

1. Building the INSERT Statement by using a stringbuilder
2. Building a DbCommand and supply it with all information
3. Execute the created DbCommand

```cs
using (IDbConnection connection = dbFactory.CreateConnection())
{
    foreach (TableDTO table in dbTables)
    {
        //build the insert statement
        StringBuilder insertSQLBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        insertSQLBuilder.Append("INSERT INTO " + table.Name + "(");

        foreach (ColumnDTO column in table.Columns)
        {
            insertSQLBuilder.Append(column.Name + ", ");                    
        }
        insertSQLBuilder.Length = insertSQLBuilder.Length - 2;
        insertSQLBuilder.Append(") VALUES (");

        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Length; i++) {
            insertSQLBuilder.Append("@param" + i + ", ");          
        }
        insertSQLBuilder.Length = insertSQLBuilder.Length - 2;
        insertSQLBuilder.Append(")");

        //prepare the insert command
        using (IDbCommand dbCommand = connection.CreateCommand()) {
            dbCommand.CommandText = insertSQLBuilder.ToString();

            IDbDataParameter[] dbParameters = new DbParameter[table.Columns.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Length; i++)
            {
                IDbDataParameter dbParameter = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
                dbParameter.DbType = typeArray[i];  //DbType Array, which holds the types for each column
                dbParameter.ParameterName = "param" + i;
                dbParameters[i] = dbParameter;
            } 

            while (dataDeserializer.MoveNext())
            {
                // get new row from json file, each element of ColumnData holds the value and extra information which is not needed here
                ColumnData[] columnData = dataDeserializer.Current;
                for (int i = 0; i < dbParameters.Length; i++)
                {
                    bool isNotGuid = typeArray[i] != DbType.Guid;
                    object value = null;
                    //TODO stupid conversion workaround
                    if (isNotGuid)
                    {
                        value = columnData[i].Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        value = Guid.Parse(columnData[i].Value);
                    }
                    dbParameters[i].Value = value ?? DBNull.Value;
                    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(dbParameters[i]);
                }
                //execute statement and close connection
                dbCommand.Connection.Open();
                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dbCommand.Connection.Close();
                dbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

What I'd like to do is to circumvent single insert calls to the database without specifying a database provider. Is there a library which support a bulk insert for multiple providers? A perfect scenario would be a library, which allows me to just change the value of a parameter and also a maximum count for rows which should be inserted at once (to keep memory usage in check).

Comment: You're pretty much always going to have provider-specific code if you need performance. Batched `INSERT` generation is the best you can do generically, but this will likely have worse performance than a provider-specific interface. For SQL Server in particular, you can't beat the performance of `SqlBulkCopy` with an approach like this; the best regular `INSERT`s can hope to achieve is to get minimal logging when inserting in an empty heap table. You could, of course, have a generic if fairly slow approach, and then detect and use provider-specific code where written.

Comment: Bulk insert means using each providers bulk insert mechanisms with commands like `BULK INSERT`,  `COPY` or `LOAD DATA INFILE`. All those work with flat files (eg CSV files). SQL, the language, doesn't describe any bulk import feature

Comment: I don't need the speed of SqlBulkCopy, but someting that at least omits some of the overhead that I'm creating. Which library would provide batch insert methods?

Comment: Explicit library recommendations are off-topic as SO questions, since they attract opinionated answers, spam and other crud that ages poorly.

Comment: Where could I ask such a question, since googling it didn't really help me so far

Comment: I've never used it myself and the site appears to be extremely lightly visited, but apparently https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is a thing. I doubt that'll get more than a web search, but still.